# Hyperledger Fabric: Adding new members to channel with private data -- can I do it without restart?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've got a channel where most but not all of the data can be viewed by all the members in the channel. However I will want to onboard new members into the channel who will need to access some of the private data. I'm using private data collections within the channel (as per recommendation from Hyperledger Fabric docs as oppposed to individual channels for the data items that are not viewable by the whole network). However it looks like I'd have to redeploy the `collections.json` file every time I onboard a new party, which is a chaincode resinstall across the network. This isn't practical.

Is there a way around this so I don't have to reinstall the chaincode for every new member that joins?

Running fabric 2.3

Comment: What fabric version are you using?

Comment: Good point -- that should have been in there.

Comment: So in 2.3 I don't think you need to re-install your chaincode, you just need to redefine it, this happens after you install. look at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/private_data_tutorial.html#deploy-the-private-data-smart-contract-to-the-channel

Answer (score 1):

As of now, every collection configuration is an explicit policy, so you need to perform an operation for each collection.

However, the [design / architecture doesn't restrict the policy to be an explicit one](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos/blob/318e632e5e0c668a1be9e1f882f814f179460766/common/collection.proto#L71-L85), and is flexible enough to accommodate a dynamic policy that is referenced and you can then update just the reference once instead of updating each collection.

Sadly, this isn't implemented yet. If you open a [JIRA](http://jira.hyperledger.org/) / [Github issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues) / [send an email in the mailing list](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric) then maybe it will be implemented at some point in the future.

It shouldn't be too hard to implement. All we need is to:

1. Stick a policy in the channel config tree.
2. Extend the `CollectionPolicyConfig` with another option of a policy reference and use the aforementioned reference.